# Associative array with multiple values in php

Tags: php, arrays

can we have associative array with multiple values for same key in php ?

example:-

```
array[key1] => value1, value2, value3
array[key2] => value4, value5, value6
```

Comment: Every value has its key.

Comment: No, but you can have array with this multiple values as the value in first array, like `array('key1' => array('value1', 'value2'))`.

Comment: key with multiple values is also an array, So here is array inside array N is called multidimensional array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
array[key1] => array(value1, value2, value3)
array[key2] => array(value4, value5, value6)
```

You can also have associative arrays in an associative array:

```
array[key1] => array(key => value1, key => value2, key => value3)
array[key2] => array(key => value4, key => value5, key => value6)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can :

```
$myvar = array (
"key_name" => array("tom", "an", "bob"), 
"key_age" => array("1", "10", "12")
);
```

and getting to those :

```
$myvar['key_name'][0];
$myvar['key_age'][0];
```

Comment: you are missing a closing ')' at the end.